# docker version calling wrong ip address

Tags: docker

when I write docker version in cmd I get this error.

```
error during connect: Get "http://127.0.0.1:12375/v1.24/version": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:12375: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d
 Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:58:50 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

It is localhost:12375 instead of localhost:2375.

Answer (score 0):

The docker command line uses the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST` to specify the url of the docker daemon to interact with.  Check where you have that value set and update with the correct URL.